# Rails link_to method parameter passing not mapping to controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to link to a specific method within a controller. My controller is called OrganismsController and the method is upload_reference_file. Through looking at other similar questions I now have a link_to working as

```
<%= link_to "Upload Reference Sequence", :controller => :organisms, :action => :upload_reference_file %>
```

However, I need to pass in the current organism to the method upload_reference_file. I've tried doing

```
<%= link_to "Upload Reference Sequence", :controller => :organisms, :action => :upload_reference_file(organism) %>
```

but rails complains that the above code is not correct syntax. 
Inside of my routes file I have the method matched to the controller action as

```
match '/organisms/upload_reference_file' => 'organisms#upload_reference_file'
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Defining "doesn't work" is almost always a good idea. Is the route defined as a restful action on a member?

Comment: I edited the question a bit for clarification. I tried doing something along the lines of     <%= link_to "Upload Reference Sequence", upload_reference_file_organism_path(organism) %>, but it to did not work.

Comment: you must declare using @organism in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a RESTful action as described in the ["Adding More RESTful Actions"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) section of the Rails Routing docs. This will create a helper method accepting a path and allow more natural usage.

For example, if you have no additional member actions:

```
resources :organisms do
  get 'upload_reference_file', :on => :member
end
```

You'll then have a `upload_reference_file_organism_path`, turning your `link_to` into:

```
<%= link_to "Upload Reference Sequence", upload_reference_file_organism_path(organism) %>
```

(In case this needs tweaking, you can get the created path name by running `rake routes`; my memory isn't so good.)

Comment: I just got match '/organisms(/upload_reference_file(/:id))' => 'organisms#upload_reference_file' to work by hard coding in the id being passed in the url, but, I like this approach a lot better. It seems to follow the rails construct more. Thanks!

Comment: @PhillipWhisenhunt Yep, this way is definitely cleaner and more Rails-y :)